# Having trouble counting files

Tags: java, hash

I have been developing a duplicate finder for some time now. The challenge I am currently facing is counting number of duplicate files found in a folder and sub folders.

What my code does is: whenever it gets to a particular file with duplicates it counts correct, but when it gets to a different file with multiples duplicates it starts from beginning.

That is not what I wanted. What I wanted is that it count total number of files with multiple duplicates.

Here is my codes:

```
public void findDuplicateFiles(File[] files) throws IOException {

    Map<String, List<File>> filesByHash = new HashMap<>();
    int number = 0;

    for (File file : files) {
        if (!file.isFile()) {
            findDuplicateFiles(file.listFiles());
            continue;  
        }
        MD5.initNativeLibrary();
        String hash = MD5.asHex(MD5.getHash(file));

        List<File> filesForHash = filesByHash.get(hash);
        if (filesForHash == null) { 
            filesByHash.put(hash, filesForHash = new ArrayList<>());
        }

        filesForHash.add(file);
    }

    for (Map.Entry<String, List<File>> entry : filesByHash.entrySet()) {
        List<File> filesForHash = entry.getValue();
        if (filesForHash.size() > 1) {
            String hash = entry.getKey();
            System.out.printf("%,d files have hash %s:%n",
                    filesForHash.size(), hash);
            int index = filesForHash.size() - 1;
            filesForHash.remove(index);
            DefaultListModel model = (DefaultListModel) list.getModel();

            for (File file : filesForHash) {
                // This is where things goes wrong  
                File fs = file.getAbsoluteFile();
                for (int i = 1; i <= fs.length(); i++);
                    number++; 
                //count.setText(number + "  Files");
                //model.addElement(file);
                System.out.println("  " + file);
                System.out.println(number + " Files");
            }
        };  
    }
    //System.out.println(" No Duplicate Found ");
}
```

Bellow is the result I get:

```
 6 files have hash da8f60e8474f7c89f368e5d6d379dcdc:
 C:\Users\Mbaegbu\Documents\Bandicam\files\bandicam 2014-07-02 10-55-03-421 -           Copy        (2).jpg
1 Files
 C:\Users\Mbaegbu\Documents\Bandicam\files\bandicam 2014-07-02 10-55-03-421 -            Copy       (3).jpg
  2 Files
  C:\Users\Mbaegbu\Documents\Bandicam\files\bandicam 2014-07-02 10-55-03-421 -           Copy      (4).jpg
  3 Files
  C:\Users\Mbaegbu\Documents\Bandicam\files\bandicam 2014-07-02 10-55-03-421 -           Copy        (5).jpg
  4 Files
  C:\Users\Mbaegbu\Documents\Bandicam\files\bandicam 2014-07-02 10-55-03-421 - Copy.jpg
  5 Files
  2 files have hash da8f60e8474f7c89f368e5d6d379dcdc:
  C:\Users\Mbaegbu\Documents\Bandicam\bandicam 2014-07-02 10-55-03-421 - Copy.jpg
  1 Files
  3 files have hash f884c30bfad89a285507d4c381700583:
  C:\Users\Mbaegbu\Documents\Bandicam\bandicam 2014-07-16 22-09-14-091 - Copy -          Copy.jpg
  2 Files
  C:\Users\Mbaegbu\Documents\Bandicam\bandicam 2014-07-16 22-09-14-091 - Copy.jpg
  3 Files
```

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: What exactly is your problem is not clear. Example would be good like these are the files, duplicates and with current solution i am getting this and i want this.

Comment: Sorry for that......I have updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you make a recursive call for each directory you encounter, but each call to your method initializes a new Map, so all the previously found files are ignored.

You should split your method to two.
One recursive method that would accept a Map as an argument and add entries to it.
One non-recursive method that would create the Map, make the first call to the recursive method and print the results based on the contents of the Map at the end.

The non-recursive method :

```
public void findDuplicateFiles(File file) throws IOException  
{
    Map<String, List<File>> filesByHash = new HashMap<>();
    if (!file.isFile())
        findDuplicateFiles(file.listFiles(), fileByHash);

    for (Map.Entry<String, List<File>> entry : filesByHash.entrySet()) {
        List<File> filesForHash = entry.getValue();
        ....
    }
}
```

The recursive method :

```
public void findDuplicateFiles(File[] files, Map<String, List<File>> fileByHash) throws IOException  
{

    int number = 0;

    for (File file : files) {
        if (!file.isFile()) {
            findDuplicateFiles(file.listFiles(),fileByHash);
            continue;
        }
        MD5.initNativeLibrary();
        String hash = MD5.asHex(MD5.getHash(file));

        List<File> filesForHash = filesByHash.get(hash);
        if (filesForHash == null) {
            filesByHash.put(hash, filesForHash = new ArrayList<>());
        }

        filesForHash.add(file);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Eran I am Still facing challanges, after following your code, nothing hapens when i run the code. Do you have idea on what to do next?